# When exporting to xml file receiving error infinite loop

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am using c# on visual studio 2015 to create a program for an assignment. I created a class for teacher information, each variable have a getter and a setter.

```
public class Teacher
{

    public string TeacherID
    {
        get { return TeacherID; }
        set { TeacherID = value; }
    }

    public string TeacherName
    {
        get { return TeacherName; }
        set { TeacherName = value; }
    }

    public string TeacherAddress
    {
        get { return TeacherAddress; }
        set { TeacherAddress = value; }
    }

    public string TeacherDob
    {
        get { return TeacherDob; }
        set { TeacherDob = value; }
    }

    public string TeacherContact
    {
        get { return TeacherContact; }
        set { TeacherContact = value; }
    }

    public string TeacherSalary
    {
        get { return TeacherSalary; }
        set { TeacherSalary = value; }
    }

    public string Class1
    {
        get { return Class1; }
        set { Class1 = value; }
    }

    public string Class2
    {
        get { return Class2; }
        set { Class2 = value; }
    }

    public string Class3
    {
        get { return Class3; }
        set { Class3 = value; }
    }

    public string Class4
    {
        get { return Class4; }
        set { Class4 = value; }
    }

    public string Class5
    {
        get { return Class5; }
        set { Class5 = value; }
    }
}
```

I created also another class names savexml to export the data from the text boxes to the xml file.

```
public class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();   
    }

}
```

I created a form with a text box for every variable and set a save button with the code below so that it will export the information to the xml file.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Teacher teach = new Teacher();
            teach.TeacherID = textBox1.Text;
            teach.TeacherName = textBox2.Text;
            teach.TeacherAddress = textBox3.Text;
            teach.TeacherDob = textBox4.Text;
            teach.TeacherContact = textBox5.Text;
            teach.TeacherSalary = textBox6.Text;
            teach.Class1 = textBox7.Text;
            teach.Class2 = textBox8.Text;
            teach.Class3 = textBox9.Text;
            teach.Class4 = textBox10.Text;
            teach.Class5 = textBox11.Text;
            SaveXML.SaveData(teach, "teacher.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The program runs fine but when I input the data and press the save button the program freezes and I receive the error below.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in UserRegistration.exe
```

I am trying to find were the issue could be but till now I can't find the problem, any help would really be great. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read up on how properties work in .NET. You're get'ing and set'ing in infinite recursion on each property. You specifically want to read up on "automatic property" and "property with backing field".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at any property in your class:

```
public string TeacherID
{
    get { return TeacherID; }
    set { TeacherID = value; }
}
```

It references to itself.

Change it to:

```
public string TeacherID { get; set; }
```

Or:

```
private string teacherID;
public string TeacherID
{
    get { return teacherID; }
    set { teacherID= value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) I tried to do the same thing beforebut kept getting an error ... the problem was that one of the private and public variables had the same name ... solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

The properties are defined in a wrong way.

```
    //Correct
    public string Class3
    {
        get; set;
    }
    //Wrong
    public string Class4
    {
        get { return Class4; }
        set { Class4 = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line return TeacherID in the getter calls the getter recursively and that leads to stack overflow. And similarly for the setter. It is same for all the properties. Due to this you are getting stackoverflow exception.